# Não estou conseguindo usar input radio para fazer outras coisas

Tags: html5, css3

Minha ideia e a seguinte, acho que se for para fazer esse tipo de validação com js vai ficar mais pesado já que vai ter que enviar mais codigo e realizar mais processo! Essa validação nao e tão importante então nao a necessidade.
Essa ideia e conveniente ou muito errada?

```css
.seletor{
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
}

#r1:checked .seletor:first-child{
  background-color: orange;
}
#r2:checked .seletor:nth-child(2){
  background-color: purple;
}
#r3:checked .seletor:nth-child(3){
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="c_1" id="r1">
<input type="radio" name="c_1" id="r2">
<input type="radio" name="c_1" id="r3">

<label for="r1">
  <div class="seletor">ooo</div>
</label>
<label for="r2">
  <div class="seletor">ooo</div>
</label>
<label for="r3">
  <div class="seletor">ooo</div>
</label>
```

Comment: Ao meu ver Se a cor eh apenas para a experiência do usuário e um feedbacks visual vc não precisa fazer validação em banco...

Answer (score 1):

AKU como falei acima no comentário da sua sua pergunta, *se a utilização da cor é apenas para a experiencia do usuário*, para orienta-lo em algum sentido e não precisa de validação no banco não há por que vc se preocupar com isso.

Sobre trocar a cor com o `RadioButton` a minha solução foi usar os seletores adjacentes e `attr[]` para chegar na `div` e trocar a cor, veja abaixo o CSS para vc entender melhor e ver funcionando. Basicamente só adicionei a linha:

```
#r1:checked ~ label[for="r1"] > div.seletor {}
```

```css
.seletor{
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#r1:checked ~ label[for="r1"] > div.seletor{
  background-color: orange;
}
#r2:checked ~ label[for="r2"] > div.seletor{
  background-color: purple;
}
#r3:checked ~ label[for="r3"] > div.seletor{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="c_1" id="r1">
<input type="radio" name="c_1" id="r2">
<input type="radio" name="c_1" id="r3">

<label for="r1">
  <div class="seletor">ooo</div>
</label>
<label for="r2">
  <div class="seletor">ooo</div>
</label>
<label for="r3">
  <div class="seletor">ooo</div>
</label>
```

Comment: te amo muito, feliz ano novo

Comment: @AKU :D que bom que gostou! Considere marcar a Resposta com "Aceita"    `✔`